# Get the views filter's value

Tags: 7, views

I'm building a views that has a PHP field with  SQL queries.
I wondering if I can get the date filter value to use it in my select statement?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [hook_views_query_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7). You can grab exposed filter values by inspecting `$_REQUEST` and grabbing the appropriate value from that array. I usually implement hook_views_query_alter and just wrap the query in a `dpm()` call (from the Devel module) so I can browse the array.

If using AJAX in your views, you'll need to refresh the page after you filter your view before Devel can print the array in your messages.

Comment: i don't use a custom module, is there another solution?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure if you'd be able to do this using Views PHP Field. You could try getting the request using dpm() in your PHP Field, and refresh the page to see if the field is getting anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [hook_views_pre_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/7)() for that.
That hook runs early and you can get filters, fields, arguments... and so.

1. Get the view object at hook_views_pre_view() time.
2. Get the filter (date) and the field (php code) using [get_item()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21view.inc/function/views_db_object%3A%3Aget_item/7) from the view. You can take a look at [views_object_tyes](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21view.inc/function/views_object_types/7) to see all kind of items you can get.
3. Look for date values and modify the php field.
4. Update the view items (in this case the php field) using [set_item()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21view.inc/function/views_db_object%3A%3Aset_item/7) .

I wonder if you should better add the php code field (sql queries) programatically, using [add_item()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21view.inc/function/views_db_object%3A%3Aadd_item/7) function.

```
<?php
function my_module_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view_name' && $view->current_display == 'my_view_display') {
    // $view_filters = $view->get_items('filter', $display_id); If you want to take a look at all the view filters
    // $view_exposed_filters = $view->exposed_input; If you need them.
    // $view_contextual_filters = $view->get_items('argument', $display_id); If you need them;

    $my_date_filter = $view->get_item($view->current_display, 'filter', 'my_date_filter');
    $my_sql_query_field = $view->get_item($view->current_display, 'field', 'my_php_field');

    // Do some stuff like:
    // Look for your values in $my_date_filter
    // Set some values in $my_sql_query_field

    // Tell drupal about the changes you've made.
    $view->set_item($view->current_display, 'field', 'my_php_field', $my_sql_query_field);
  }
}
```

I have never tried with date filters, but I think it should work.